# Use Number to convert string to numbers in a copy of an array after using slice and spread operator

Tags: javascript, type-conversion, spread

I wasn't able to find an exact solution or if it is even possible.
I have an example array and I wont be using the first two values, and I wanted to transform those strings to numbers with `Number()` and using the spread operator to convert each value in one go.

```js
let array = ['1','2','3','4','5','6']
let result = Number(...array.splice(2));
```

the result of this is 3 is there a way to use the spread operator? or the only way out of this is to use map.

The expected result is `result = [3,4,5,6]` so only numbers. The array of strings is just an example, it might have more strings inside or less.

Comment: Use `+` instead of `Number(...)`, `+('1') // 1`

Comment: It returns `3` because splicing the array returns the removed items (`['3', '4', '5', '6']`) and using the spread operator puts `'3'` as the first argument, which then returns `3`

Comment: How exactly should the endresult look like? [3, 4, 5, 6] ?

Comment: "*using the spread operator to convert each value in one go.*" - that's not how spread syntax works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Number constructor converts one value to a number - **Number(value)**

You're putting in as value a spreaded array from which the first value is taken and converted

```js
Number(...array.splice(2))  // Number('3','4','5','6') => 3
```

I don't see any good example using the spread operator, since you don't want to get rid of the array structure, but have to iterate the array for converting each element from string to number

1. For getting rid of the first two entries **without altering the original array** use **.slice()** The second argument can be omitted if you want to slice from the index to the end of the array
2. To keep it short you can directly map on the spliced array using either the Number(v) constructor or by simply adding the + at the front

```js
let array = ['1','2','3','4','5','6']
let numbers1 = array.slice(2).map(str => +str) // [3, 4, 5, 6]
let numbers2 = array.slice(2).map(str => Number(str)) // [3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Thanks i see that i cant expect the spread to work in this case scenario.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is slice the array (to remove the two first elements) and then map, transform the numbers from string to number:

```
let array = ['1','2','3','4','5','6']
let result = array.slice(2, array.length)
let numbers = result.map(el=>Number(el))
console.log(numbers)
```

Comment: Correct, map would do the work. But wanted to see why if the spread operator returns every instance of the returned array ['3','4','5']  im only getting the first value instead of transforming every value to Number.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose to use `splice`, but you don't want the result. You just want to run that to remove the first 2 values. Then map the remaining values to an array of numbers and you're good.

```js
let array = ['1','2','3','4','5','6'];
array.splice(0, 2); // splice will remove indexes 0 and 1
let result = array.map(n => +(n)); // map the remaining values to numbers
console.log(result);
```